# Is it legal to distribute e-books in a company (NL)?

Tags: copyright, commerce

If a company owns copies of several e-books that have commercial licenses, can it distribute these e-books to employees? For instance with software like Koha.

If not, is there a common other way to achieve this?

And just to clarify, the company wouldn't have rights to reproduce the e-books. Also, a distribution where only one employee at a time would have access to one book is sufficient.

Thanks!

Comment: The company can do what the licence says it can do. The words "commercial license" tell us nothing.

Comment: What does "(NL)" in the title mean?

Comment: NL = The Netherlands